# IOS push notifications not working in ad hoc mode

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ad-hoc-distribution

Hey there I'm trying to test my application in the ad hoc mode for release.
I don't have any problems testing it in the developper mode.
What I've done:
I created the certificate as described here in [apple-push-notification-services-in-ios](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1). Once for developer and once for the distribution/ad hoc.

Now if I'm starting the adhoc mode I can get my device token by printing it on the screen, so I think there should not be any fault in the generation of the certificates on apple developer. And I know that developer and distribution device token are different.
But if I'm testing app to send message, I won't receive any message however I received one test message when I was running app using developer settings.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it or what might be wrong?

Comment: Did you change the .pem(or any other file being used on server so that server code uses the Private Key corresponding to APNS Production Certificate) in use on your server? 
EDIIT:Also, if I am not mistaken URL for production APNS is different from development. Did you change that?

Comment: Yes I changed the .pem file to the distribution .pem file. Ah didn't know that they different. Silly mistake if that solfes the problem

Comment: and the URL as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this solution in another forum:

Sandbox: `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, port 2195` (for the development)

Production: `gateway.push.apple.com, port 2195` (for the release)

Thank you for your help and hope others might use this